# Regex to find word and not other word between 2 other words across multiple lines in Java

Tags: java, regex, eclipse

I need to search multiple xhtml documents looking for the following:
any tag where there's the string **action=** but not the string **update=**
I'm using the Eclipse Search, so i need the regex in Java format

If i'm not wrong this can be achieved with the following (i also ignore spaces between **action/update** and **=** )

```
^(?!.*update\s*=).*action\s*=.*$
```

My problem is a single line search like this would not be enough, since html tags could span across multiple lines.

So, i would need to look between the **<** and the **>** of the tag, even if on different line.

Can that be achieved?

Example lines i want to match (i don't care if the  part gets ignored:

```
<a href="#" action="test" update="test_container"></a>

<a href="#" action="test2"
 update="test_container2"></a>

<mytag href="#" update="test_container3"
action="test3" />
```

Comment: [Regex is **NOT** a good tool to parse HTML/XML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/5784924).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`action=`, but not `update=` inside `<...>`:

```
<([^>](?!update\s*=))*action\s*=([^>](?!update\s*=))*>
```